# tf.print gives TypeSpec TypeError

Tags: tensorflow

What does this error message mean?

```
TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for name: "tf.print/PrintV2"
op: "PrintV2"
input: "tf.print/StringFormat"
attr {
  key: "end"
  value {
    s: "\n"
  }
}
attr {
  key: "output_stream"
  value {
    s: "stdout"
  }
}
 of unsupported type <class 'google3.third_party.tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation'>
```

I'm printing the shape of a tensor.  My code "works" without the print, so I'm sure it is this statement, and the tensor is valid.  I can print the shape of a tensor in a test colab. I'm clueless how to narrow this down and debug this.  My failure is in a big hairy program.

I can't find any information on the web about what might be causing this error.

What does it mean when I get a TypeSpec error from a tf.print?

-- Malcolm
(TF 2.7.0)

Comment: Are you trying to print an intermediate layer in a `Keras` model?

Comment: No.  Printing within a Keras (functional) pipeline, not a Layer.

Comment: The problem is much deeper... seems to be related to a TPU strategy and an keras input.  But I'd still like to know what the error message means.

Comment: I have the same issue, when trying to call tf.print on an intermediatory tensor in my functional keras model

Comment: As the first commenter noted, are you printing a Keras tensor?  They are not the same as regular TF tensors.  I don't know how you get a Keras tensor, perhaps the output of a graph that is contains Keras blocks?

Comment: Can you share reproducible code snippet. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry for the tardy followup.

Turns out that the output from Keras layers is not a regular tf.tensor. I still don't understand the reason, the error message, or how to give a better message.  :-(

Here is a simple example of the problem (and the error message) and an (undocumented) solution.

```
import tensorflow as tf
keras_input = tf.keras.layers.Input([10])
tf.print(keras_input)
==> TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for name: "tf.print_2/PrintV2"


tf.keras.backend.print_tensor(keras_input)
==> <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 10) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'tf.keras.backend.print_tensor')>
```

So the moral of the story is use tf.keras.backend.print_tensor when working with Keras models.

Comment: Your answer help me quite a lot, but there is a little problem, `tf.keras.backend.print_tensor(keras_input)` won't be executed at runtime, because it's not associated in the graph, to associate, change to `keras_input = tf.keras.backend.print_tensor(keras_input)`, as the document says http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/TensorFlow.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/print_tensor.html.