# How to show a full tensor in keras backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to debug an existing keras model and want to see some specific tensors in a custom loss function. I know I can use keras.backend.print_tensor but this only prints a truncated tensor. I know there is no way to print the full tensor using keras.backend.print_tensor but is there any other way to save or print or in any other way display the full tensor?

Comment: `tf.print(tensor, summarize=-1)`

Comment: @AloneTogether tf.print does not work on kerastensors

Comment: Do you know what a `Keras` tensor is?

Comment: @AloneTogether see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007364/tf-print-gives-typespec-typeerror

Comment: See your question. You are talking about tensors in a loss function not an Input layer. Maybe provide some details